# Object array gets overwritten by the last object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array of objects being loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("<div></div>").load("/Stats/Contents #stats", function () {
    statcount = $(".list-group-item", this).length;

    for (var j = 0; j < statcount; j++) {
      statList.push(stat);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < statcount; i++) {
      statList[i].statId = document.getElementById("statId-" + (i + 1) + "").value;
      statList[i].productDescription = document.getElementById("productType-" + (i + 1) + "").value;
      statList[i].lastMeasuredInventoryAmount = document.getElementById("statLastMeasureAmount-" + (i + 1) + "").value;
    }
  )}
)}
```

.... and so on
Then I get the changed values and save them, however, in the ajax post call, all of the array objects are same (the last one assigned), looks like they get overwritten.
Any ideas? I saw these deferred/promise type code but not sure if there's simpler way.
Thanks.

Comment: From where did silo come? is this the complete code?

Comment: You are showing us a function that takes some data with an unknown structure and applies to some markup, also unknown. Without knowing the two, your question is meaningless.

Comment: Without the HTML it's hard to say, but my guess would be that all your `statId-`, `productType-` and `statLastMeasureAmount-` DOM elements have exactly the same ID, which would explain why JS always picks the last one.

Comment: Sorry Naren - correction, that should read "statList.push(stat);" stat is the object containing data.

Comment: @masterfloda - no, they don't have same id, they are dynamic elements and have ids like statId-1, statId-2 and so on and when I debug the javascript - it goes through the for loop and correctly gets all the values and pushes them in the array. However, that gets overwritten later I could not find out how.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - markup is meaningless here. The issue - the object array gets populated correctly using the for loop, and I don't do anything with it - but when I call the ajax post to send it to the MVC action - the debug shows the whole array with values of the last object.

Comment: @EkjonS So at the end of the .load() callback function, the statList array is correct? Can you show us your JS that does the ajax POST?

Comment: $(".saveButton").click(function () {      
        var statData = JSON.stringify(statList);        
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Stats/Save",
            type: "POST",
            data: statData,
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {                
                generateAlert("saved.", "success");    
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {               
                generateAlert("error occurred", "error");
            }
        });
    });

Comment: So, when it reaches json post, it already has incorrect data, even before hitting the server.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you take the statList array and then push that up to the server, with any respective change.  Rather than building and maintaining a list like this, have you thought of switching it around and just grabbing the results out of the markup and building up the array at save point?

```
$("btnSave").on("click", function(e) {
   var data = [];
   $(".list-group-item").each(function() {
     data.push({
       statId: $(this).find(".statid").val(),
       .
       .
     })
   });
```

You wouldn't need to give every element an ID (but could) as my sample uses CSS classes to find the element within the current list item.  Additionally, if these are inputs, you could serialize them from the root element more efficiently...

Comment: Hi Brian - Yes, I could do that - however, the requirement is I send both the original data and edited data back with the post. That's why I need to capture and keep the original on first load.

Comment: Also, the ids are dynamically generated like statid-1, statid-2 - hence the need for the dynamic array and push. And they come from the database but some are editable.